# HTML form generation from the database and store value into the database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, entity-attribute-value

I have a "t_form" table and a "t_attribute" table. It looks a little bit like below.

**Form table**

```
form_id | form_name    | description
-----------------------------------
1       | Laptop       | Possible attributes are Model, Screen Size, OS, Cd Player
2       | Mobile       | Possible attributes are Model, OS
3       | Tablet       | Possible attributes are Model, Screen size, OS
```

**Attribute table**

```
attribute_id | attribute
------------------------
1            | Model
2            | Screen Size
3            | OS
4            | Cd Player
```

1. Possible attributes of type Laptop form are Model, Screen Size, OS, Cd Player.
2. Possible attributes of type Mobile form are Model, OS.
3. Possible attributes of type Tablet form are Model, Screen size, OS.

**Form_Attribute table**

```
form_id | attribute_id
----------------------
1       | 1 
1       | 2
1       | 3
1       | 4
2       | 2
2       | 2
3       | 2
3       | 2
3       | 2
```

I will generate the HTML form like below(with form fields) according to the selection of form type(either Laptop, Mobile or Tablet) by the user from the database.

**For Laptop:**

[image]

**For Mobile:**

[image]

**For Tablet:**

[image]

**Questions:**
Here are my questions.

1. What is better approach to store the data entered by the user into the database.
2. What is better approach to retrieve the data from the database, because I want to achieve the filter option, *for example*: I want to fetch the result which laptop screen size is avilable from 14 to 16.

**Filter:**

[image]

Please provide a feasible solution with some example for better understanding to me and help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can go for a table like

Form_Attribute_Values or Items

```
item_id |    form_id | attribute_id | value
------------------------------------------------
1       |    1       | 1            |  SuperLap
1       |    1       | 2            |  15
1       |    1       | 3            |  MS-DOS 6
1       |    1       | 4            |  Toshiba
```

In this way you will be able to query the single item entered, but also to filter by Form, Attribute or Attribute Value.

You Form_Attribute table will be very handy generating the form for a specific Form (i.e. when a user wants to enter a Laptop or a Mobile phone).

The Items table will be the place where you will store the items after an insert or where you will look to query them.

You can also add at the end a timestamp column to store when the item was saved and a User_id column if your data will be populated by multiple users. And maybe an additional column for the availability too if you can store items not available in store or you can keep availability in a separate table.

A query for a laptop with screensize 14-16 will be like this if you can get the form and attribute id from your filtering form:

```
    SELECT item_id, 
           form_name, 
           attribute_name,
           value
INNER JOIN form 
        ON item.form_id = form.form_id 
INNER JOIN attribute 
        ON item.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id 
     WHERE item_id IN (-- here I select for Laptop and Screen Size dimension
                       SELECT item_id 
                         FROM item
                        WHERE form_id = 1
                          AND attribute_id = 2
                          AND item.value BETWEEN 14 and 16
                      )
```

Otherwise you will need something a bit more complicated:

```
    SELECT item_id
      FROM item
INNER JOIN form 
        ON item.form_id = form.form_id 
INNER JOIN attribute 
        ON item.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id 
     WHERE item_id IN (-- here I select for Laptop and Screen Size dimension
                       SELECT item_id 
                         FROM item
                        WHERE form_id = (-- but first I need the form_id 
                                         -- for Laptop
                                         SELECT form_id 
                                           FROM form 
                                          WHERE form_name = 'Laptop')
                          AND attribute_id = (-- then I need the attribute_id 
                                              -- for Screen Size
                                              SELECT attribute_id 
                                                FROM attribute 
                                               WHERE attribute_name = 'Screen Size')
                          AND item.value BETWEEN 14 and 16
                      )
```

Comment: Regarding performance, I am asking this question.

The "value" field for the table "Form_Attribute_Values" will be of type char/varchar for sure because it holds many type of values such as INT for Screen Size, VARCHAR for Model.

If I store the "screen size" as a separate column, the fetching time will be very fast, so how to achive the higher performance.

Comment: I think we should worry about performance if you are looking for entering in that table millions of rows. If you expect to have only few thousands of Items/attributes you shouldn't worry too much. You are right a numeric field will be faster, but then you have to manage different columns for different type of values. The best solution for querying would be to create a completely different table structure with a column for each attribute (then you will be free to define them of the right datatype), but this means also to populate and maintain that table. Are you ready for this? :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply mucio, Yes it is a commercial project, in future there will be more than millions of rows. Can you suggest any better database design approach?

Comment: Can you please tell me with some sample data, I am not getting clear. 
Tell me for entry for the form type laptop, I want to store the data (Possible attributes of type Laptop form are Model, Screen Size, OS, Cd Player) in the database. How to store this in the table as per the second approach?

Comment: einterview if you are going to work with millions of rows you will need something more than StackOverflow. That said for querying purpose what you need is a dimensional model. I suggest you to start with the Kimball Data Warehouse Toolkit book, that will open you a whole new world

Comment: keep in mind that often what is optimized for input is not optimized for reporting on it, this is way there is need for ETL in the middle. On Kimball's book you will find a lot of examples retail related

Comment: Can you tell me about ETL or any link. I have googled for ETL, is it any approach/concept in mysql. Whether we can achieve ETL in mysql?

Comment: Whether the `item_id` in Form_Attribute_Values or Items table is primary key or not?

Comment: Instead of `value` field in `Form_Attribute_Values or Items` table, May I alter the table with another 3 fields, like `value_int` hold integer values, `value_varchar` hold varchar values, `value_text` hold text values, but in this scenario every row will contain null values for sure. Is it better?  or Or May you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your attributes are growing for the form field means, it will be easy to use JASON data format to store this record into non relational DB like MongoDB. Then you can easily query the MongoDB Jason data.

If you are using the Relational Model means the above Answer 1 would be best fit.

Comment: Thanks Vel for your input, planned to use relational model